# VBA delete all slides in one go

Tags: vba

I have found a piece of code to delete all ppt slides one by one except the the Active one (Index 1). However, can any one help me in re-writing this code to action the code in one hit. I don't want to loop each and every slide as there will be about 300 slides to delete. This is the code I have:

```
Sub Deleteslides()

'This deletes all slides except Active Main one.

Dim Pre As Presentation
Set Pre = ActivePresentation
Dim x As Long
For x = Pre.Slides.Count To 2 Step -1
    Pre.Slides(x).delete
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub Deleteslides()

    Dim Pre As Presentation, arr(), x As Long, n As Long
    Set Pre = ActivePresentation
    ReDim arr(0 To Pre.Slides.Count - 2)
    n = 0
    For x = Pre.Slides.Count To 2 Step -1
        arr(n) = x
        n = n + 1
    Next x
    Pre.Slides.Range(arr).Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting all of your slides, presumably so you can keep your template, why not just save a template and work from that? Have your application close the presentation and open a new one with the template?

Comment: Yes, This is an option two. I will think about this.Thank you.